# When writing a bash script, how do I get the absolute path of the location of the current file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, paths

Suppose I have a bash file called `myBash.bash`. It resides in:

```
/myDirect/myFolder/myBash.bash
```

Now I want to use the string `/myDirect/myFolder` (the location of `myBash.bash`) inside the script. Is there a command I can use to find this location?

Edit: The idea is that I want to set-up a zip-folder with code that can be started by a bash script inside that zip-file. I know the relative file-paths of the code inside that zip-file, but not the absolute paths, and I need those. One way would be to hard-code in the path, or require the path of the file to be given as a variable. However I would find it easier if it was possible for the bash-file to figure out where it is on its own and then create the relevant paths to the other file from its knowledge of the structure of the zip-file.

Comment: This might be better suited for stackoverflow. Check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within.

Comment: use how.? please clarify

Comment: @SethosII this question is totally on topic here

Comment: @Zanna `pwd` returns your current directory (from where you run the scirpt) not the scripts location. And just for clarification: it's about bash scripting, which is part of ubuntu, but isn't it more about programming then the distribution itself?

Comment: I added more context to the question. I thought there might be an easy/obvious command to get the file-path of the file that is executing, but it seems the answer is at least non-obvious.

Comment: @Zanna I don't say it's offtopic, i think it's just more appropriate and as shown with the links already asked and answered there multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! The answer is indeed to take the zeroth argument of the bash-file and then use functions like dirname and realpath to get where you want to be.  My apologies that I wasn't able to find the previous questions on this topic

Comment: Questions that have been answered 8 years ago on StackOverflow, have been viewed about a million times, and have over 4000 upvotes aren't very suited to post here. Well I guess it's not a duplicate here.

Comment: Please note that sometimes there _is_ no path. For example: `cat /foo/bar | bash`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can get the full path like:

```
realpath "$0"
```

And as [pointed out by Serg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893911/when-writing-a-bash-script-how-do-i-get-the-absolute-path-of-the-location-of-th/893927?noredirect=1#comment1399126_893927) you can use `dirname` to strip the filename like this

```
dirname "$(realpath $0)"
```

or even better to prevent awkward quoting and word-splitting with difficult filenames:

```
temp=$( realpath "$0"  ) && dirname "$temp"
```

Much better than my earlier idea which was to parse it (I knew there would be a better way!)

```
realpath "$0" | sed 's|\(.*\)/.*|\1|'
```

#### Notes

- `realpath` returns the actual path of a file
- `$0` is this file (the script)
- `s|old|new|` replace `old` with `new`
- `\(.*\)/` save any characters before `/` for later
- `\1` the saved part

Comment: +1 for use of `$0` and `sed` magic. But the said `sed` magic is really unnecessary when tools like `dirname` exist

Comment: you already have the answer , use `realpath`: `realpath "$( dirname $0 )"` I personally would use `readlink` but that's me: `readlink -e $(dirname $0)`

Comment: @Serg: Wouldn't `dirname "$(realpath "$0")"` be better? Usually one wants to know the parent directory of the referenced file instead of the parent directory of the symbolic link referring to said file.

Comment: @Serg `"$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"` is the most straightforward way. Quotes inside `$()` work as normal.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel    Did a bit of research online, you're right: `$()` being a subshell will allow having quotes outside. I wouldn't say it's as straightforward though, unless one realizes `$()` are all subshells

Comment: @DepressedDaniel has stated the actual most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer seems perfect. Here's another way to do it:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
/bin/pwd
```

`/bin/pwd` prints the real path of the directory, as opposed to the `pwd` builtin command.

Answer (score 5):

if the script is in your path you can use something like

```
$ myloc=$(dirname "$(which foo.sh)")
$ echo "$myloc"
/path/to/foo.sh
```

EDIT: after reading comments from Serg, this might be a generic solution which works whether the script is in your path or not.

```
myloc==$(dirname "$(realpath $0)")
dirname "$myloc"
```

Comment: `which` is more suitable for when script resides in one of the directories that are part of `PATH` variable.  Use `$0` from within a script, just like Zanna shows. But your answer is proper since you use `dirname` instead of messing with `sed`, hence +1 for that

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
wdir="$PWD"; [ "$PWD" = "/" ] && wdir=""
case "$0" in
  /*) scriptdir="${0}";;
  *) scriptdir="$wdir/${0#./}";;
esac
scriptdir="${scriptdir%/*}"
echo "$scriptdir"
```

It is taken as reference from [kenorb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20265752/11620356) and [andro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23162801/11620356)
No dirname, readlink, realpath, BASH_SOURCE
All are builtins

Comment: It's the best solution I found. Simple, easy, clear, working.

Comment: Beautiful solution